# How to negate this statement of locally bounded function?

Tags: real-analysis

A function is said to be locally bounded if for given $M$ and $\alpha$ such that $\forall x \in (a-\alpha, a+\alpha) \cap A$ , $|f(x)| \leq M$.

Taking $\alpha = \frac{1}{n}$

Book writes as $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists x_n \in (a-\frac{1}{n}, a + \frac{1}{n})$ such that $|f(x_n)| > n.$

I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "locally bounded" you mean "locally bounded at $a$
", i.e. " bouned on some small interval around $a$
". And you must replace "for given" with "there exist".

So, the statement we want to negate is:
$$\exists M,\alpha>0\quad\forall x \in (a-\alpha, a+\alpha) \cap A\quad|f(x)| \leq M.\tag{1}$$

But before negating it, let us prove it is equivalent to
$$\exists n\in\Bbb N\quad\forall x \in (a-1/n, a+1/n) \cap A\quad|f(x)| \leq n.\tag{2}$$

$(2)\implies(1)$ is obvious. For $(1)\implies(2),$ note that if $n\ge M$ and $\frac1n\le\alpha,$ then $\forall x \in (a-\alpha, a+\alpha) \cap A\quad|f(x)| \leq M$ implies $\forall x \in (a-1/n, a+1/n) \cap A\quad|f(x)| \leq n$ (because $(a-1/n, a+1/n)\subset (a-\alpha, a+\alpha)$ and $M\le n$). Therefore, given $M,\alpha>0,$ we can just choose any integer $n$ satisfying both $n\ge M$ and $n\ge\frac1\alpha$, i.e. $n\ge\max(M,1/\alpha).$

Now, the negation of (2) is the statement you quoted from your book.

Comment: @SophieClad Good job! Let us delete all our comments now. (I only leave this one, so that future readers can guess that contrary to appearances, this is *really not* an answer to a "no effort question".)